# Condition of Existence of $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty}A^m$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Claim** Let $A$ be a $square \; matrix$ with complex entries and let $S = \{\lambda \in \Bbb C \mid |\lambda|<1 \;or\; \lambda =1\}$

Then $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty}A^m$ exists if and only if both of the following hold:

1) Every eigenvalue of $A$ is contained in $S$

2) If 1 is and eigenvalue of $A$, then the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to 1 equals the multiplicity of 1 as an eigenvalue of $A$

**Question**

How to prove the necessity of condition 2)?
for 1), I could easily verify, however, not for 2).

Comment: The question has some major issues. Do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty} A^n$? You can type `\mathbb C` for $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I made a mistake. Edited.

Comment: Think about $$\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}.$$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown that one dieverges with a violoation to condition2) with multiplicity 2

Comment: @user251257 any difference between \mathbb and \Bbb ?

Comment: @jackerysmith nope. I wouldn't just type $C$. That was what I meant.

Comment: @user251257 I was always wandering what Bbb means or bb means.. are they denoting some kind of space?

Comment: @jackerysmith bb stand for blackboard bold. That kind of styling was first used on blackboards as making letter bold was/is cumbersome. It is just a kind of emphasis and is often used for particular well-known sets.